# Using come or comes

Tags: grammar, verbs, present-tense

There is a song written by the songwriter "Saint Mesa" called *Fire* that includes the line:

> I see fire /
> Come from below

[Full lyrics](https://genius.com/artists/Saint-mesa)

I am not a native english speaker and I can't understand why it's "come" when my knowledge of English grammar suggests "comes" should be used.

Comment: It could be dialect. Who is Saint Mesa and where do they come from?

Answer (score 2):

- "I see fire *come* from below" describes a *single* event.
- "Fire *comes* from below" is a general statement about where fire comes from.

You would probably have understood it better if they'd said "I *saw* fire come from below", but as an artistic device, the lyrics are written in the present tense, as if the first person is describing what they can see in real-time.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct as it is. ***See*** is a verb of perception. [Englishgrammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/) explains that

> ***Hear, see, watch, notice*** and similar ***verbs of perception*** can be followed by *object + infinitive* without to or *object + -ing form*.

Sometimes a difference in the use of these verbs with bare infinintive or -ing form can be made.

> ***The infinitive*** is used after these verbs when we want to say that *we hear or see the whole of an action or event.* ***The –ing form*** is used to suggest that *we hear an action or event in progress.*

Thus for example:

> - I ***heard her sing*** a lovely song. (As I sat listening, she started singing a song and I listened to her until she finished it.)

whereas

> - I ***heard her singing*** a song as I walked past her room. (When I heard her she was singing a song – she was probably in the middle of her singing. Anyway, I didn’t hear the entire song.)

So in your sentence

> I ***see*** fire ***come*** from below.

*fire* is the object and it is followed by a bare infinitve. This indicates that the author of the sentence considers the action of *come* as an event in itself, and is less concerned with its duration.